# SQL - how to use CASE

Tags: sql

```
Select Lastname, Firstnme, Sex, 

Case When Sex = F Then ‘female’ Else ‘male’ End 

Birthdate From Employee Order by Lastname
```

This is my code, but the case statement will not work this way, hoe can I realize it?

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't Sex = F be Sex = 'F', with the quotes?

Comment: And also presumably you aren't using smart quotes in your actual code? (i.e `''` vs. `‘’`)

Comment: Which Database are you using?

Comment: its the IBM DB2 database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want something like:

```
select Lastname, Firstnme, 
Sex = Case 
     When Sex = 'F' Then ‘female’ 
     Else ‘male’ 
     End, 
 Birthdate 
 From Employee Order by Lastname
```

The difference here is you have to set Sex = Case and then put a comma after the case statement so it knows Birthdate is another field.

This was written for SQL server, if you're using MySql, or some other RDBMS your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think you need to end the CASE with "AS [Name]"

Comment: Depends, if it's SQL Server, you don't according to Example A in this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: Just because SQL lets you do something or the docs use it in an example doesn't imply it is best practice :) I strongly recommend **against** using anonymous columns.

Answer (score 4):

Put 'F' in quotes :

```
Select Lastname, Firstnme, Sex, 
Case 
When Sex = 'F' Then 'female' 
When Sex = 'M' Then 'male'
ELSE 'Unknown'
End as Sex_string, Birthdate 
From Employee Order by Lastname
```

Or

```
Select Lastname, Firstnme, Sex, 
Case Sex
When 'F' Then 'female' 
When 'M' Then 'male'
ELSE 'Unknown'
End as Sex_string, Birthdate 
From Employee Order by Lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, birthdate, sex,
     CASE sex
       WHEN 'F' THEN 'Female'
       WHEN 'M' THEN 'Male'
       ELSE 'Unknown'
     END AS gender
FROM EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY lastname;
```

You could leave the second `WHEN` clause out of the `CASE` clause and just let the `ELSE` clause handle anything that is not female, but typically there are three values for gender - male, female and unknown. The above script accounts for a third variable and will return all records as either male, female, or unknown.